# How to fix broken Gitlab secrets

Tags: gitlab

I run a gitlab in my k3s cluster at home and try to setup all I need to play around.

If I try to edit-save a user or a project the server returns Error code 500. "We're sorry. Something went wrong on our end."

if I run `gitlab-rake gitlab:doctor:secrets` I have some failers.

```
- User failures: 2
- Project failures: 2
- Ci::Runner failures: 1
```

I was able to fix ApplicationSetting failures but can not find any information how to fix the other issues. Last time this happened I deleted my PV and let gitlab create a new installation. But this can't be the way how to fix it each time. It's nice to have this doctor check your DB and tell you what's wrong but now I need to fix them other then starting with a fresh installation each time.

there is a very long entry in the logs, i guess that is the important part, don't want to paste this endless error completly `"exception.class":"OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError","exception.message":""`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the errors you're receiving or it may be closed. Also please get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them like you are now!

Comment: I'm reading this error for several hours now (over many days and many weeks), I'm not ignoring it, it just don't tell me anything useful. I tried to enhance the question with as much information as possible.